# How to source from stdout for both Linux and MacOS?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, terminal, macos

On Linux I can do:

```
source <(cat .env | grep ANDROID_GRADLE_TASK)
```

But on MacOS, this doesn't do anything (no error, and no source)

I have tried to replace -di with --decode --input, it didn't help.

1. What can I use for MacOS?
2. Is there a command that works both on Linux (Debian/Ubuntu) and MacOS?

Comment: What works depends on your shell; this uses Bash syntax, so it will work in Bash on a Mac too; but MacOS now defaults to Zsh for new users.

Comment: What exactly this does depends on what's in `.env`; if you need it to be portable between shells, that's a topic we can't answer without seeing the code. (That's a useless `cat` , by the way.)

Comment: Actually, for whatever reason, that doesn't seem to work in Bash 3.2 (which is the Bash that I understand macs still have). It does work in zsh, though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only portable way is to do this:

```
grep ANDROID_GRADLE_TASK .env > .x; source .x
```

The other option is to install bash 5 from brew on the Mac.

Comment: That might run, but it won't be very useful. The parts of a pipeline run in subshells, and the point of `source` is to run in the _same_ shell. E.g. if you try `echo foo=bar | source /dev/stdin`, you can check that `foo` does _not_ get set. You might try with `lastpipe` set, but it doesn't work in interactive shells (though I'm not sure if that's a problem in the context here)

Comment: Odd I tested it just now, worked

Comment: ok, right, it does work in zsh. In Bash you'll need `lastpipe`.

Comment: `source` is not portable, it is a bash alias for the standard POSIX `.` command (change `source .x` to `. .x`)